# How do I ensure that old shared content is removed when using Module::Build's share_dir option?

Tags: perl, module-build

I'm using `Module::Build`'s `share_dir` option to install read-only supplementary content when users install my Perl module.

How do I ensure that the old content added by previous versions of my module is deleted when a new version of my module is installed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yanick Champoux has recently been dealing with [this problem](http://babyl.dyndns.org/techblog/entry/sharedir-tarball). To do so he has created [File::ShareDir::Tarball](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aShareDir%3a%3aTarball) and its Dist::Zilla counterpart [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::ShareDir::Tarball](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aShareDir%3a%3aTarball). The idea is that your entire sharedir is tarred so that it is only one directory. Then when your module is upgraded, the tarball is replaced and it is in the state you expect.

Comment: FWIW, that solution doesn't appeal to me :) I would rather use `sub share { dist_file(  'File-ShareDir',  "2012-11-02/@_"); }` that way older files don't interfere with newer code, even if they aren't removed

Comment: @sonotlikeopenid.anonymity, that and your answer are both good ideas, I simply posted something that is already implemented. I have no opinion about which is best. :-)

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the least-bad option in my particular case.

Comment: versioned directories is also a possibility. I played with the idea, but then, if the previous module version is gone anyway (because that one got clobbered for sure by the install), why bother keeping the old shared files around too?

Answer (score 1):

If you're removing files from a distribution I recommend making Makefile.PL or Build.PL refuse to install, add this

```
my $mod = 'CGI';
if( eval "require $mod; 1" ){
  die "

YOU HAVE TO UNINSTALL $mod before you can upgrade, use one of
cpanp -u  $mod  --force
pm-uninstall -vf $mod


";
}
```

Or better yet, add a pre-amble which does the actual uninstalling (maybe with ExtUtils::Install::uninstall($packlist) )

Usually you'll know which version of your module requires complete uninstalling, so you might want to add a version check ...

FWIW, this would make a good Module::Build/Module::Install/ExtUtils::MakeMaker addition/extension/plugin that accepts something like

```
requires_uninstall_if_installed  => '<3000' ,
requires_uninstall_if_installed  => { CGI => '<3000', 'CGI::Util' => '<3000' },
requires_uninstall_if_installed  => [ qw' CGI CGI::Util '],

requires_uninstall_if_installed( '<3000' );
requires_uninstall_if_installed( { CGI => '<3000', 'CGI::Util' => '<3000' } );
requires_uninstall_if_installed( [ qw' CGI CGI::Util '] );
```

Comment: Actually it wouldn't be very hard to make a Module::Build subclass which does somehow cleans either the share dir or the entire old module during (probably just before) `ACTION_install`.

Comment: see possible implementation here: https://github.com/jberger/Module-Build-CleanInstall

Comment: Thanks, @sonotlike. This is a good strategy, and I'll fall back to this if I can't make File::ShareDir::Tarball work for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have now uploaded [`Module::Build::CleanInstall`](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aCleanInstall) to hopefully address issues like this. Hopefully it helps. A big thanks goes to Yanick and so-not-like-openid-anonymity for the inspiration.